# Google Drive insert file permission

Tags: c#, rest, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I can't insert permission to a file with this code:

```
string URI = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{0}/permissions&access_token={1}", fileId, "token");

var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json"; 

string json = "{\"role\": \"reader\",\"type\": \"anyone\"}";

byte[] byteData = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(json);

request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I al getting a 404 error. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string URI = String.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{0}/permissions&access_token={1}", fileId, "token");
```

Access token is not a string **"token"** it must be a valid access token for the user who owns the file.

**Update:**

```
permissions?access_token={1}",
```

You should be using `?` and not `&` to add a parameter to the url.  Not even sure you can do it like that with a HTTP Post.

**Added info:**

1. If this is not simply a typo on your part you may want to read up on [Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert#auth) a little
2. I also recommend checking out the Google client library instead of writing this yourself.   [Google.Apis.Drive.v2 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/).
3. There is a newer version of the Google Drive API you might also be interested in looking at rather then writing new code for an older version of the API.  [Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk).

Comment: yes I write "token", but it is Access_token from Authorization request

Comment: Double check your file id then it may not be correct or the authenticated user may not have access to it.   Do file.list to check.

Comment: I changed the uri to "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{0}/permissions?alt=json&prettyPrint=true&access_token={1}" and now work